# Why does this heap sort method work with <T> but not with a wildcard <?>?

Tags: java, generics, methods, wildcard

I have implemented it with the Priority queue because of the task.
My question is why it is working like this:

```
public <T> void heapSort(List<T> elements){
    PriorityQueue<T> q = new PriorityQueue<>(elements);

    elements.clear();
    while (!q.isEmpty()){
        elements.add(q.poll());
    }
}
```

But it stops working when I change it with a wildcard?

```
public void heapSort(List<?> elements){
    PriorityQueue<?> q = new PriorityQueue<>(elements);

    elements.clear();
    while (!q.isEmpty()){
        elements.add(q.poll());
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message do you get with `?`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please, someone, explain to me why?

In general, you can't add elements from a `PriorityQueue<?>` into a `List<?>`, because the queue might be a `PriorityQueue<String>` and the list might be a `List<Integer>`.

The compiler doesn't "remember" that the type parameter is the same in both cases, unless you create a type variable to tell it they are the same.

> and how to fix it.

You know  how to fix it: use a type variable, as in the first code example.

If you mean how not to have the type variable in the method signature, you can delegate to a private method:

```
public void heapSort(List<?> elements) {
  heapSortPrivate(elements);
}

private <T> void heapSortPrivate(List<T> elements){

    PriorityQueue<T> q = new PriorityQueue<>(elements);
    elements.clear();
    while (!q.isEmpty()){
        elements.add(q.poll());
    }
}
```

Comment: This principle is illustrated (as a "capture helper") in a [helpful article by Brian Goetz.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04298/index.html#30) I recommend it to help understand these concepts more fully.